# Passing multiple values to other acitivity class

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an JSONArray that gets multiple pairs of longitude and latitude and I want to use Intent to pass the multiple pairs into another class, it was previously working fine as it only pass in a pair of longitude and latitude.

Was thinking if i could still use intent to pass or I need to use an ArrayList to store and call one by one out in the other class?

Kindly advise. Thanks.

This is my json array:

```
{"longitude":"101.9366229","latitude":"1.236459"},{"longitude":"101.930041","latitude":"1.224119"}]}
```

My code for intent to prepare to pass:

```
   Intent i = new Intent(this, BorrowerMap.class);
                i.putExtra("username", username);
                i.putExtra("longitude", Longitude);
                i.putExtra("latitude", Latitude);
                startActivity(i);
```

My code for intent to get the values:

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            username = extras.getString("username");
            Longitude = extras.getDouble("longitude");
            Latitude = extras.getDouble("latitude");
        }
```

I would like to be able to print longitude":"101.9366229","latitude":"1.236459, longitude":"101.930041","latitude":"1.224119" in the other class separately.

Comment: you can put a hash in between and split the string in the next activity eg (coord = lat1+"#"+lng1+"#"+lat2+"#"+lng2)

Comment: you can try using a `Serializable class`  for parsing your json and then sending the `object` of that `Serializable class` to another activity. simple ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the json string to the next class.

Example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, BorrowerMap.class);
            i.putExtra("data", "{"longitude":"101.9366229","latitude":"1.236459"},{"longitude":"101.930041","latitude":"1.224119"}]}");
            startActivity(i);
```

And then do Json manipulation in the BorrowerMap class?

Comment: This don't really work as the json will return me this way? 102.9366229,1.236459
102.930041,1.224119. It will only pass the last pair which is 102.930041,1.224119

Answer (score 0):

try this,

for sending data,

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        HashMap<String, String> h1=new HashMap<String, String>();
        h1.put("username", username);
        h1.put("longitude", longitude);
        h1.put("latitude", latitude);

        list.add(h1);

        Intent next=new Intent(First.this,Second.class);
        next.putExtra("list", list);
        startActivity(next);
```

next.putExtra() is a parceblevalue not string.

for receiving data.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        list=(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getExtras().get("list");

        String uName=list.get(0).get("username");
        String lat=list.get(0).get("longitude");
        String long=list.get(0).get("latitude");
```

you convert it in string when sending.

```
String lat=latitude+"";
String lang=longitude+"";
```

and when receiving it in double.

```
double lat=Double.parseDouble(stringlat);
        double lang=Double.parseDouble(stringlang);
```

Comment: Hi there, just to note that my longitude and latitude is double type. Do I need to change anything in the code?

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure why it only returns me the second latitude and longtitude but not the first one, first one returns me 0,0.